# Regular Expressions (A or A or A&B), (A but not B)

Tags: php, regex

can someone help me please to build a regular expressions on a string, my colleague ask me for it but i never found any Regular Expressions for A&B or A^B.

This is my actual code

```
'(Eclipse|Sun)' => array(
                     'Got' =>  'Power 50',
                     'World' => 'EU'),);
```

How can i perform an regular expressions to have the choice between :
"Eclipse" OR "Sun" OR "Eclipse&Sun".

My second question is about [^] for list which characters that i DON'T want.
How can i perform an regular expressions for saying "Eclipse[^Oracle]"
Because i want to select string with "Eclipse" but i don't want to have string with "Eclipse" and "Oracle".

```
'Eclipse[^Oracle]' => array(
                     'Note' =>  'Density 200',
                     'City' => 'Prague'),);
```

Comment: You can start here [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: I'm seeing it, but doesn't found what i wanted. Because Oracle is not attached with Eclipse, it's more like "bla oracle for bla Eclipse bla"

Comment: @hwnd Do you have any solution please? or can you explain me more about regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question:** How can i perform an regular expressions to have the choice between : "Eclipse" OR "Sun" OR "Eclipse&Sun".

**Answer:** You can use alternation to accomplish this. Like so:

```
(Eclipse&Sun|Eclipse|Sun)
```

The way that alternation works, is that if it matches the first expression it will not try the second and third. You need to take that into account when creating the expression.

---

> **Question:** How can i perform an regular expressions for saying "Eclipse[^Oracle]" Because i want to select string with "Eclipse" but i don't want to have string with "Eclipse" and "Oracle".

**Answer:** If you want to match something only while a different word is not present, you can use Positive Lookaheads to validate the string before matching it. Like so:

```
^.*(?=^.*(Eclipse))(?!^.*Oracle).*$
```

- The match will PASS if Eclipse exists `(?=^.*Eclipse)`

  - It will place 'Eclipse' into a capture group backreferenced as number `1`
- The match will FAIL if Oracle exists `(?!^.*Oracle)`

---

**Regex demo here:**

[Regex101, Positive Lookaheads](http://regex101.com/r/dS8yO7)

Answer (score 0):

First: `Eclipse OR Sun OR (Eclipse AND Sun) <=> Eclipse OR Sun`

```
if (preg_match('~\b(?:Eclipse|Sun)\b~', $str)) {
...
} else { ... }
```

Second: `Eclipse^Oracle`

```
if (preg_match('~(?=.*\bEclipse\b)(?!.*\bOracle\b)~', $str)) {
```

`(?=...)` followed by
`(?!...)` not followed by